# Not able connect mobile to WAMP

Tags: php, android, apache

I am using WAMP(version 2.4.9) to host a local server on my pc. My pc is connected to wifi and the ip address is 10.192.48.252 . The port is 420. When I type http://10.192.31.222:420/ in the browser of pc, I get the wampserver homepage as it should be but when I type in the same address in my mobile browser, I get the following error

```
Forbidden 
You don't have permission to access / on this server
```

I have connected both my pc and mobile over same wifi network. I have set "Require all granted" in httpd.conf file and made 420 accessible through firewall. Please help.

Comment: Do you have try with your local address ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also having the same issue as yours. Try XAMPP. Its working fine for me. It has no port issue.